# VScode extension for changing Multiline `Postfix` for long commands (powershell to shell)?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a **vscode extension** out to help me? I found nothing on the marketplace. May I search with the wrong key words :-)

If there is no extension available, may a js-snippet would help, then I can wrap it myself in a extension. Or any other ideas to solve the issue, to convert these two formats would help.

I wrote documentaion for docker commands, which become often very long, so I need to wrap the lines. The docu should cover shell and powershell syntax.

> My question is not limited to docker, but is a use case.

I am aware of `\` (slash) or shell and also `` ` `` (backtick) for poweshell. And also the different usages of pwd, like `$pwd` and `${PWD}`.

Here one example command, in bash

```
docker run \
  --interactive \
  --tty \
  --env PORT=8123 \
  --publish 8123:8123 \
  --name my-running-script \
  -v "$PWD":/usr/src/app \
  -w /usr/src/app \
  node:latest node server.js
```

Here same example command, in powershell

```
docker run `
  --interactive `
  --tty `
  --env PORT=8123 `
  --publish 8123:8123 `
  --name my-running-script `
  -v "${PWD}":/usr/src/app `
  -w /usr/src/app `
  node:latest node server.js
```

The extension / snippet should do the change from the line postfix (line wrpaper) from `\` to `` ` `` and also the change from `$PWD` to `${PWD}` and maybe also the other way round.

**HINT**: This question was asked on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75332766/10655742) first, and I moved it here.